# Writing a 4D array as a 3D vectorising 2 dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4D array with dimensions as follows:

```
In [3]: flrev.shape
Out[3]: (9, 12, 143, 144)
```

From this array (flrev), I want to create a 3D array (dyn) with dimensions (9,12,20306).

This array will be produced when:

- from flrev(:,:,0,:) I take only the first value flrev(:,:,0,0)
- from flrev[:,:,1:-1,:] I take all values, so flrev[:,:,1:-1,:]
- from fl[ff,ll,-1,:] I take only the first value flrev[ff,ll,-1,0]

I tried to do this by looping and using np.ravel function:

```
phys = np.empty(([flrev.shape[0],flrev.shape[1],143*142]))
for ff in range(flrev.shape[0]):
    for ll in range(flrev.shape[1]):
        for ss in range(flrev.shape[2]):
            for kk in range(flrev.shape[3]):
                if flrev[ff,ll,ss,kk] == flrev[ff,ll,0,kk]:
                    phys[ff,ll,:] = np.ravel(flrev[ff,ll,0,0])
                elif flrev[ff,ll,ss,kk] == flrev[ff,ll,1:-1,kk]:
                    phys[ff,ll,:] = np.ravel(flrev[ff,ll,1:-1,:])
                elif flrev[ff,ll,ss,kk] == flrev[ff,ll,-1,kk]:
                    phys[ff,ll,:] = np.ravel(flrev[ff,ll,-1,0])
```

The error that I get is:

```
     47       if flrev[ff,ll,ss,kk] == flrev[ff,ll,0,kk]:
     48           phys[ff,ll,:] = np.ravel(flrev[ff,ll,0,0])
---> 49       elif flrev[ff,ll,ss,kk] == flrev[ff,ll,1:-1,kk]:
     50           phys[ff,ll,:] = np.ravel(flrev[ff,ll,1:-1,:])
     51       elif flrev[ff,ll,ss,kk] == flrev[ff,ll,-1,kk]:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any idea on how to do this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `flrev[ff,ll,1:-1,kk]` has many values, right?  So the comparison with one value will produce a boolean array, many True/False.  But an `elif` can only do one thing, not many.  So that expression doesn't make sense.

Comment: But given the word description, I don't see why you are comparing values in the `if` expressions.  I can see comparing indices, `ss` with `kk` etc.  But from the word description I don't think you need to iterate.

Comment: `phys[ff,ll,:] = np.ravel(flrev[ff,ll,0,0])` could I think be written as `phys[:,:,:] = np.ravel(flrev[:,:,0,0])`, eliminating the need for `ff` and `ll` iterations.  Is the fact that you use `144` in one place and `142` in another intentional?

Comment: I agree with what you write, but I can't think of how I can choose specific values without iterating. If I had to take all the values of the initial 4D array and convert it to a 3D one, then yes, there's no need to do this; this is not the case here.

Comment: As the error says, if you want all the array to be equal just use: `elif np.all(flrev[ff,ll,ss,kk] == flrev[ff,ll,1:-1,kk]):`

Comment: Same problem: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()